# In a brick breaker game programmed in java, how should I prevent the velocity from reversing twice if it hits two bricks at the same time?

Tags: java

i am creating a brick breaker game in java. I am having a small issue. In scenarios where the ball hits two bricks at once, instead of it bouncing back it goes straight through due to the fact that when the ball hits a brick, its velocity is reversed so when it hits two bricks at the same time, the direction of the ball doesn’t change. Here is my code for that part of the method

```
    // ball hits brick
    for (int i = 0; i < bricks.size();i++){
        if ((ball.getBounds().intersects(bricks.get(i).getBounds()) 
        && (!bricks.get(i).getHit()))){
            bricks.get(i).Hit();
            bricks.get(i).Isvisible();
            vy = (vy * -1);
            scorein ++;

        }
    }
```

Vy represents the Y Axis velocity of the ball, reversing the velocity changes the direction of the ball. Please help me thank you.

Comment: Instead of performing your "hit" tasks on every brick, make a list of bricks that get hit and do the "hit" stuff once

Comment: The only task of the hit method is to set the hit variable of that specific brick object to true so that the ball wont hit it again, the actual velocity task is being done by the line vy = (vy * -1), if I misunderstood your advice please let me know.

Comment: You make a list of bricks.  Process the list: Each brick gets hit.  Only do the velocity change once, regardless of how many bricks got hit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a flag to detect a single collision on each update. Something like this:

```
//On each frame
Update() {
vyUpdated = false;

//other game logic
...
// ball hits brick
for (int i = 0; i < bricks.size();i++){
    if ((ball.getBounds().intersects(bricks.get(i).getBounds()) 
    && (!bricks.get(i).getHit()))){
        bricks.get(i).Hit();
        bricks.get(i).Isvisible();
        if (!vyUpdated)
            vy = (vy * -1);
        vyUpdated = true;
        scorein ++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by each frame? For each brick object?

Comment: Ohhh nevermind i understand what you mean, thank you very much!